# Reading Data From UDP socket

Tags: networking, udp, tcp

I use the following function to read from a file descriptor...

```
int cread(int fd, char *buf, int n){

  int nread;

  if((nread=read(fd, buf, n))<0){
    perror("Reading data");
    exit(1);
  }
  return nread;
}
```

Following is the function that uses the above function

```
if(FD_ISSET(tap_fd, &rd_set)){
  /* data from tun/tap: just read it and write it to the network */

  nread = cread(tap_fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);

  tap2net++;
  do_debug("TAP2NET %lu: Read %d bytes from the tap interface\n", tap2net, nread);

  /* write length + packet */
  plength = htons(nread);
  nwrite = cwrite(net_fd, (char *)&plength, sizeof(plength));
  nwrite = cwrite(net_fd, buffer, nread);

  do_debug("TAP2NET %lu: Written %d bytes to the network\n", tap2net, nwrite);
}
```

They both work fine with TCP siocket but not with udp socket.. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `tap_fd` in the file descriptor set for the UDP case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your problem is, but if `net_fd` is a UDP socket, then the two `cwrite()` calls will create *two* UDP datagrams.

There isn't a great deal of point in prepending the size with UDP - UDP maintains the message boundaries for you.  So in the UDP case, just remove the `plength` part entirely.